# dev c++ error:no matching for function

Tags: c++, matching

Below I have 2 .cpp and 1 .h file. This program sets up and implements a custom  class for working with distances.  When I run I get this error which i looked for hours but couldn't figure out what its about. distance.cpp compiles smoothly, however, when I run main.cpp I get this error below:

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Executing  g++.exe...
g++.exe "C:\Users\Himalaya\Desktop\C++\cs1600\distance_class\main.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Himalaya\Desktop\C++\cs1600\distance_class\main.exe"    -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\include"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\backward"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include"   -L"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib" 
C:\Users\Himalaya\Desktop\C++\cs1600\distance_class\main.cpp: In function `void addDistances(Distance, Distance)':
C:\Users\Himalaya\Desktop\C++\cs1600\distance_class\main.cpp:92: error: no matching function for call to `Distance::Distance(Distance)'
C:\Users\Himalaya\Desktop\C++\cs1600\distance_class\/distance.h:20: note: candidates are: Distance::Distance(Distance&)

C:\Users\Himalaya\Desktop\C++\cs1600\distance_class\main.cpp: In function `void subtractDistances(Distance, Distance)':
C:\Users\Himalaya\Desktop\C++\cs1600\distance_class\main.cpp:102: error: no matching function for call to `Distance::Distance(Distance)'
C:\Users\Himalaya\Desktop\C++\cs1600\distance_class\/distance.h:20: note: candidates are: Distance::Distance(Distance&)

C:\Users\Himalaya\Desktop\C++\cs1600\distance_class\main.cpp: In function `void sumDistanceArray(Distance*)':
C:\Users\Himalaya\Desktop\C++\cs1600\distance_class\main.cpp:116: error: no matching function for call to `Distance::Distance(Distance)'
C:\Users\Himalaya\Desktop\C++\cs1600\distance_class\/distance.h:20: note: candidates are: Distance::Distance(Distance&)

C:\Users\Himalaya\Desktop\C++\cs1600\distance_class\main.cpp: In function `void plotDistanceArray(Distance*)':

C:\Users\Himalaya\Desktop\C++\cs1600\distance_class\main.cpp:148: warning: converting to `int' from `double'

Execution terminated
```

here is my distance.h

```
#ifndef DISTANCE_H
#define DISTANCE_H

#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Distance
{
private:
    double inches;
    int feet;

public:
    Distance();
    Distance(int ft, double in);
    Distance(Distance &dist);
    void setInches(double in);
    double getInches();
    void setFeet(int ft);
    int getFeet();
    bool operator==(Distance &dist);
    Distance operator+(Distance &dist);
    Distance operator-(Distance &dist);
    string showDistance();

};

#endif // DISTANCE_H
```

here is the distance.cpp

```
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "distance.h"

using namespace std;

Distance::Distance()
{
    feet = 0;
    inches = 0;
}

Distance::Distance(int ft, double in)
{
    this->feet = ft;

    if(in >= 12)
    {
        while(in >= 12) // pull as many feet as possible out of inches
        {
            this->feet += 1;
            in -= 12;
        }
        this->inches = in;  // store remainder
    }
    else
    {
        this->inches = in;
    }
}

Distance::Distance(Distance &dist)
{
    this->feet = dist.feet;
    this->inches = dist.inches;
}

void Distance::setInches(double in)
{
    if(in >= 12)
    {
        while(in >= 12) // pull as many feet as possible out of inches
        {
            this->feet += 1;
            in -= 12;
        }
        this->inches = in;  // store remainder
    }
    else
    {
        this->inches = in;
    }
}

double Distance::getInches()
{
    return this->inches;
}

void Distance::setFeet(int ft)
{
    this->feet = ft;
}

int Distance::getFeet()
{
    return this->feet;
}

bool Distance::operator==(Distance &dist)
{
    if((this->feet == dist.feet) && (this->inches == dist.inches))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

Distance Distance::operator+(Distance &dist)
{
    Distance dist_return;
    double total_inches = 0;
    dist_return.feet = this->feet + dist.feet;
    total_inches = this->inches + dist.inches;
    if(total_inches >= 12)
    {
        while(total_inches >= 12) // pull as many feet as possible out of inches
        {
            dist_return.feet += 1;
            total_inches -= 12;
        }
        dist_return.inches = total_inches;
    }
    else
    {
        dist_return.inches = this->inches + dist.inches;
    }

    return dist_return;
}

Distance Distance::operator-(Distance &dist)
{
    Distance dist_return;
    int temp_feet = this->getFeet(); // copy "this" so we can do math and show properly
    double temp_inches = this->getInches();

    dist_return.feet = temp_feet - dist.feet;
    dist_return.inches = temp_inches - dist.inches;

    dist_return.feet = abs(dist_return.feet);
    dist_return.inches = abs(dist_return.inches);  // distance is never negative, and - means difference, so 12 - 20 = 8

    return dist_return;
}

string Distance::showDistance()
{
    string str_return = "";
    std::ostringstream temp_str_holder;

    if(this->feet > 0)  // only print feet if we have any
    {
        temp_str_holder.str("");  // clear out ostringstream
        temp_str_holder << this->feet;
        str_return += temp_str_holder.str();

        if(this->feet == 1)
        {
            str_return += " foot";
        }
        else
        {
            str_return += " feet";
        }
    }

    if(this->inches > 0)  // only print inches if we have any
    {
        if(this->feet > 0)
        {
            str_return += " ";  // if we have both feet and inches, print spacer between terms
        }

        temp_str_holder.str("");  // clear out ostringstream
        temp_str_holder << this->inches;
        str_return += temp_str_holder.str();

        if(this->inches == 1)
        {
            str_return += " inch";
        }
        else
        {
            str_return += " inches";
        }
    }

    if((this->feet == 0) && (this->inches == 0))  // if 0 feet 0 inches, just say 0 inches
    {
        str_return = "0 inches";
    }

    return str_return;
}
```

and main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include "distance.h"


using namespace std;

void addDistances(Distance dist1, Distance dist2);
void subtractDistances(Distance dist1, Distance dist2);
void sumDistanceArray(Distance dist_array[]);
void plotDistanceArray(Distance dist_array[]);
void calcRectangle(Distance dist1, Distance dist2);

int main()
{
    Distance dist1;  // showing initialization using defaults
    dist1.setInches(6.7);
    Distance dist2(1,7);  // showing initialization to a distance
    Distance dist3(0,34);  // showing the auto-conversion of inches to feet as needed
    Distance dist4(dist3);  // showing initialization to another distance object's values
    dist4.setFeet(4);
    Distance dist_array[4] = {dist1, dist2, dist3, dist4};
    int menu_entry;
    bool menu_exit = false;

    do
    {
        //display menu
        cout << endl << endl << endl;
        cout << "***** Main Menu *****" << endl;
        cout << "1: Add two distances" << endl;
        cout << "2: Subtract two distances" << endl;
        cout << "3: Sum an array of distances" << endl;
        cout << "4: Plot an array of distances" << endl;
        cout << "5: Calculate the perimeter and area of a rectangle" << endl;
        cout << "6: Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter the number of your selection: ";
        cin >> menu_entry;
        cin.ignore(256,'\n'); // clear input buffer of remaining data

        // check entry, warn and promt again if invalid
        if ((menu_entry < 1) || (menu_entry > 6))
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Invalid entry! Please try again." << endl;
            continue;
        }

        //choose and run function based on user menu selection
        switch (menu_entry)
        {
            case 1:
                addDistances(dist2, dist3);
                break;
            case 2:
                subtractDistances(dist2, dist3);
                break;
            case 3:
                sumDistanceArray(dist_array);
                break;
            case 4:
                plotDistanceArray(dist_array);
                break;
            case 5:
                calcRectangle(dist2, dist3);
                break;
            case 6:
            default:
                menu_exit = true;  //if we picked 6 then exit
                break;
        }
    }
    while(!menu_exit);

    return 0;
}

void addDistances(Distance dist1, Distance dist2)
{
    Distance dist_total;
    dist_total = dist1 + dist2;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "The sum of " << dist1.showDistance() << " and " << dist2.showDistance() << " is "
         << dist_total.showDistance() << endl;
}

void subtractDistances(Distance dist1, Distance dist2)
{
    Distance dist_total;
    dist_total = dist1 - dist2;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "The difference of " << dist1.showDistance() << " and " << dist2.showDistance() << " is "
         << dist_total.showDistance() << endl;
}

void sumDistanceArray(Distance dist_array[])
{
    int i;
    int num_distances = 4;
    Distance dist_total;
    for(i=0; i<num_distances; i++)
    {
        dist_total = dist_total + dist_array[i];
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "The sum of: " << endl;
    for(i=0; i<num_distances; i++)
    {
        cout << dist_array[i].showDistance() << endl;
    }
    cout << "is " << dist_total.showDistance() << endl;
}

void plotDistanceArray(Distance dist_array[])
{
    int i;
    int j;
    double inches;
    double bar_percentage;  // percentage of total columns bar takes up
    int bar_length;  // number of columns bar is long
    int num_distances = 4;
    int num_feet_max = 6;  // the max of the graph scale
    int num_max_disp_columns = 60;  // the number of max columns a bar can take up

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Plot of an array of distances (6 ft scale): " << endl;

    for(i=0; i<num_distances; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(20) << dist_array[i].showDistance() << " ";

        inches = dist_array[i].getInches() + (12 * dist_array[i].getFeet());
        bar_percentage = inches / (num_feet_max*12);
        bar_length = bar_percentage * num_max_disp_columns;  // calculate bar length

        for(j=0; j<(bar_length+1); j++)
        {
            cout << "#";  // draw bar
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void calcRectangle(Distance dist1, Distance dist2)
{
    Distance rect_area;
    Distance rect_perimeter;
    double inches1;
    double inches2;

    inches1 = dist1.getInches() + (12 * dist1.getFeet());
    inches2 = dist2.getInches() + (12 * dist2.getFeet());

    rect_area.setInches(inches1 * inches2);
    rect_perimeter.setInches((2 * inches1) + (2 * inches2));

    cout << endl;
    cout << "A rectangle with dimensions " << dist1.showDistance() << " and " << dist2.showDistance() << " has an area of "
         << rect_area.showDistance() << " and a perimeter of " << rect_perimeter.showDistance() << endl;
}
```

I believe the solution is very easy however being rookie at this makes me unable to do so even if i looked into same issue on internet. What am i doing wrong here?

Edited Version

```
#ifndef DISTANCE_H
#define DISTANCE_H


#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Distance
{
private:
    double inches;
    int feet;

public:
    Distance();
    Distance(int ft, double in);
    Distance(const Distance &dist);
    void setInches(double in);
    double getInches();
    void setFeet(int ft);
    int getFeet();
    bool operator==(const Distance &dist);
    Distance operator+(Distance &dist);
    Distance operator-(Distance &dist);
    string showDistance();

};

#endif // DISTANCE_H


#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "distance.h"

using namespace std;



Distance::Distance()
{
    feet = 0;
    inches = 0;
}

Distance::Distance(int ft, double in)
{
    this->feet = ft;

    if(in >= 12)
    {
        while(in >= 12) // pull as many feet as possible out of inches
        {
            this->feet += 1;
            in -= 12;
        }
        this->inches = in;  // store remainder
    }
    else
    {
        this->inches = in;
    }
}

Distance::Distance(const Distance &dist)
{
    this->feet = dist.feet;
    this->inches = dist.inches;
}

void Distance::setInches(double in)
{
    if(in >= 12)
    {
        while(in >= 12) // pull as many feet as possible out of inches
        {
            this->feet += 1;
            in -= 12;
        }
        this->inches = in;  // store remainder
    }
    else
    {
        this->inches = in;
    }
}

double Distance::getInches()
{
    return this->inches;
}

void Distance::setFeet(int ft)
{
    this->feet = ft;
}

int Distance::getFeet()
{
    return this->feet;
}

bool Distance::operator==(Distance &dist)
{
    if((this->feet == dist.feet) && (this->inches == dist.inches))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

Distance Distance::operator+(Distance &dist)
{
    Distance dist_return;
    double total_inches = 0;
    dist_return.feet = this->feet + dist.feet;
    total_inches = this->inches + dist.inches;
    if(total_inches >= 12)
    {
        while(total_inches >= 12) // pull as many feet as possible out of inches
        {
            dist_return.feet += 1;
            total_inches -= 12;
        }
        dist_return.inches = total_inches;
    }
    else
    {
        dist_return.inches = this->inches + dist.inches;
    }

    return dist_return;
}

Distance Distance::operator-(Distance &dist)
{
    Distance dist_return;
    int temp_feet = this->getFeet(); // copy "this" so we can do math and show properly
    double temp_inches = this->getInches();

    dist_return.feet = temp_feet - dist.feet;
    dist_return.inches = temp_inches - dist.inches;

    dist_return.feet = abs(dist_return.feet);
    dist_return.inches = abs(dist_return.inches);  // distance is never negative, and - means difference, so 12 - 20 = 8

    return dist_return;
}

string Distance::showDistance()
{
    string str_return = "";
    std::ostringstream temp_str_holder;

    if(this->feet > 0)  // only print feet if we have any
    {
        temp_str_holder.str("");  // clear out ostringstream
        temp_str_holder << this->feet;
        str_return += temp_str_holder.str();

        if(this->feet == 1)
        {
            str_return += " foot";
        }
        else
        {
            str_return += " feet";
        }
    }

    if(this->inches > 0)  // only print inches if we have any
    {
        if(this->feet > 0)
        {
            str_return += " ";  // if we have both feet and inches, print spacer between terms
        }

        temp_str_holder.str("");  // clear out ostringstream
        temp_str_holder << this->inches;
        str_return += temp_str_holder.str();

        if(this->inches == 1)
        {
            str_return += " inch";
        }
        else
        {
            str_return += " inches";
        }
    }

    if((this->feet == 0) && (this->inches == 0))  // if 0 feet 0 inches, just say 0 inches
    {
        str_return = "0 inches";
    }

    return str_return;
}




#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include "distance.h"


using namespace std;

void addDistances(Distance dist1, Distance dist2);
void subtractDistances(Distance dist1, Distance dist2);
void sumDistanceArray(Distance dist_array[]);
void plotDistanceArray(Distance dist_array[]);
void calcRectangle(Distance dist1, Distance dist2);

int main()
{
    Distance dist1;  // showing initialization using defaults
    dist1.setInches(6.7);
    Distance dist2(1,7);  // showing initialization to a distance
    Distance dist3(0,34);  // showing the auto-conversion of inches to feet as needed
    Distance dist4(dist3);  // showing initialization to another distance object's values
    dist4.setFeet(4);
    Distance dist_array[4] = {dist1, dist2, dist3, dist4};
    int menu_entry;
    bool menu_exit = false;

    do
    {
        //display menu
        cout << endl << endl << endl;
        cout << "***** Main Menu *****" << endl;
        cout << "1: Add two distances" << endl;
        cout << "2: Subtract two distances" << endl;
        cout << "3: Sum an array of distances" << endl;
        cout << "4: Plot an array of distances" << endl;
        cout << "5: Calculate the perimeter and area of a rectangle" << endl;
        cout << "6: Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter the number of your selection: ";
        cin >> menu_entry;
        cin.ignore(256,'\n'); // clear input buffer of remaining data

        // check entry, warn and promt again if invalid
        if ((menu_entry < 1) || (menu_entry > 6))
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Invalid entry! Please try again." << endl;
            continue;
        }

        //choose and run function based on user menu selection
        switch (menu_entry)
        {
            case 1:
                addDistances(dist2, dist3);
                break;
            case 2:
                subtractDistances(dist2, dist3);
                break;
            case 3:
                sumDistanceArray(dist_array);
                break;
            case 4:
                plotDistanceArray(dist_array);
                break;
            case 5:
                calcRectangle(dist2, dist3);
                break;
            case 6:
            default:
                menu_exit = true;  //if we picked 6 then exit
                break;
        }
    }
    while(!menu_exit);

    return 0;
}

void addDistances(Distance dist1, Distance dist2)
{
    Distance dist_total;
    dist_total = dist1 + dist2;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "The sum of " << dist1.showDistance() << " and " << dist2.showDistance() << " is "
         << dist_total.showDistance() << endl;
}

void subtractDistances(Distance dist1, Distance dist2)
{
    Distance dist_total;
    dist_total = dist1 - dist2;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "The difference of " << dist1.showDistance() << " and " << dist2.showDistance() << " is "
         << dist_total.showDistance() << endl;
}

void sumDistanceArray(Distance dist_array[])
{
    int i;
    int num_distances = 4;
    Distance dist_total;
    for(i=0; i<num_distances; i++)
    {
        dist_total = dist_total + dist_array[i];
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "The sum of: " << endl;
    for(i=0; i<num_distances; i++)
    {
        cout << dist_array[i].showDistance() << endl;
    }
    cout << "is " << dist_total.showDistance() << endl;
}

void plotDistanceArray(Distance dist_array[])
{
    int i;
    int j;
    double inches;
    double bar_percentage;  // percentage of total columns bar takes up
    int bar_length;  // number of columns bar is long
    int num_distances = 4;
    int num_feet_max = 6;  // the max of the graph scale
    int num_max_disp_columns = 60;  // the number of max columns a bar can take up

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Plot of an array of distances (6 ft scale): " << endl;

    for(i=0; i<num_distances; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(20) << dist_array[i].showDistance() << " ";

        inches = dist_array[i].getInches() + (12 * dist_array[i].getFeet());
        bar_percentage = inches / (num_feet_max*12);
        bar_length = bar_percentage * num_max_disp_columns;  // calculate bar length

        for(j=0; j<(bar_length+1); j++)
        {
            cout << "#";  // draw bar
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void calcRectangle(Distance dist1, Distance dist2)
{
    Distance rect_area;
    Distance rect_perimeter;
    double inches1;
    double inches2;

    inches1 = dist1.getInches() + (12 * dist1.getFeet());
    inches2 = dist2.getInches() + (12 * dist2.getFeet());

    rect_area.setInches(inches1 * inches2);
    rect_perimeter.setInches((2 * inches1) + (2 * inches2));

    cout << endl;
    cout << "A rectangle with dimensions " << dist1.showDistance() << " and " << dist2.showDistance() << " has an area of "
         << rect_area.showDistance() << " and a perimeter of " << rect_perimeter.showDistance() << endl;
}
```

I changed it the way you told me however still the same issue. After trying that I changed for all the distances (for instance for operators too) I changed them to constant, still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the signature of Distance(Distance &) to Distance(const Distance &). The point is that the temporary value dist1 + dist2 won't be matched by "Distance &," but it will be matched by  "const Distance &".

Comment: I know its too much to ask but could you possibly show me the version you think it might work?

Comment: In Distance.cpp and Distance.h, simply replace all occurrences of the text "Distance(Distance &dist)" with "Distance(const Distance &dist)"

Comment: i did what you said however it did not work, i was wondering do i have to change  operator==(Distance &dist) to operator(const Distance &dist ) too? I did it only for what you said however it did not work,  check above for the changed version according to the what you have said.

Comment: No matter what i do i cant get it to work :S could you please send me regarding how you got it worked to my address enesfurkan@hotmail.com
this is very important for me.

Comment: Hmmm, your original code compiles without error for me with g++ 4.7. What version of g++ are you using?